# Read a single noise level form arecord C

Tags: c, linux, audio, microphone, recording

I am having a bit of a problem with using arecord. I have been searching the web for approximately 3 hours now and have still not found an answer.

All I want is to read a single noise level from the microphone and output it to the console. I have found many solutions involving writing it to a file but I am completely lost on just simply reading a single noise level.

Hopefully someone can shed light on my situation.